# Dataset of multiple judges or examiners giving scores

Tags: data-request, education

I am looking for a publicly available data set of (ideally) the following kind.

1. Multiple (must be 3 or more) examiners each grade the academic
   work (e.g., essay, dissertation, term-assignment) of multiple
   (ideally 20 or more) students.
2. Every examiner grades every student.
3. In addition to the grade given by each examiner to each student,
   there is a single "comprehensive" grade for each student given by
   faculty, based (in some manner that is transparent) on the other
   grades.

An example might be where all Honors-level dissertations are marked by the four members of a faculty examining committee.  The description is of an ideal example, but I'd be very pleased to learn of other similar open-data examples where the grade involves some degree of "judgement" on the part of the examiner. I'm not looking, for example, for a dataset where multiple people ("examiners") record their reading from a measuring instrument (i.e., give a grade) under multiple conditions (equivalent to "multiple students")

Comment: What about figure skating championships?

Comment: It's a nice idea. I previously had a look at the Olympic diving scores which are somewhat similar and I might have to settle for some sort of Olympic data ... but I'd really like to find an example related to academic grades. There is a dataset I saw written up (I think in the British Medical Journal) relating to hundreds of different examiners grading thousands of prospective medical practitioners but I couldn't extract a large enough (sub)set meeting the kinds of conditions I described.

Comment: Did you find any good dataset?

Comment: @abc Unfortunately I did not but I'd be interested to know what use you were thinking of for such a data set.

Answer (score 1):

It may be hard to find a dataset that matches your exact criteria, but there are some promising open datasets with essay scoring.

---

- [Kaggle Automated Essay Scoring](https://www.kaggle.com/c/asap-aes), (link to [data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/asap-aes/data), requires registration)

> The data will contain ASCII formatted text for each essay followed by one or more human scores, and (where necessary) a final resolved human score.
>
> Where it is relevant, you are provided with more than one human score, so that you may evaluate the reliability of the human scorers

You can find code for benchmarks [here](https://github.com/benhamner/ASAP-SAS).

---

- [International Corpus of Learner English](http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/%7Epersingq/ICLE/orgDataset.html), (link to [data](http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/%7Epersingq/ICLE/OrganizationScores.txt))

> Data available on this page include annotated organization scores for 1,003 essays from the International Corpus of Learner English (ICLE).

Comment: The two data sets are interesting and I appreciate knowing about them.

Comment: archive of the second dataset: https://web.archive.org/web/20190228093110/http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~persingq/ICLE/OrganizationScores.txt