# Sentencing decisions

Tags: legal

In the book "[Noise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316451401)" by Kahneman, Sibony & Sunstein, extensive reference is made to a study by [Clancy, Bartolomeo, Richardson and Wellford (1981)](https://scholarlycommons.law.northwestern.edu/jclc/vol72/iss2/7). I'm particularly interested in the study [because](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/dataset-of-multiple-judges-or-examiners-giving-scores) multiple decision makers made decisions about a single, complete set of data. Does anyone know whether the dataset for the study is available?